# C# Winforms - Bind DataGrid Columns to properties in nested objects

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagrid that displays a list of custom objects. This list contains objects who's properties are storing other objects:

```
class Survey
{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public Answer ChosenAnswer{get;set;}
 public Question SomeQuestion{get;set;}
}
```

Right now the grid simply gives me the type of the objects stored in Survey properties.

So if I have a list of Survey, for example, how would I go about binding columns of my data grid to properties of Answer?

Do I need to work with the BindingSource?

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
            bindingSource.DataSource = surveys;            
            dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Where surveys is the list..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement a ToString for Answer and Question classes, those will be displayed in the column. Hope thats what you need.